# remove migrations files in Django

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I have a Django project and I want to delete all migrations files inside the project with python.
I did that with those commands, but I want to remove them with python.

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc" -delete
```

Comment: Exactly *why* do you want to remove the migration files?

Comment: I want to make Django command to remove migrations files when I reset database

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea to remove migrations, but you can try something like this:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

for curdir, dirs, files in os.walk('your_app_root'):
    if 'migrations' in curdir:
        for file in files:
            if file != '__init__.py':
                path = Path(curdir).absolute() / file
                os.remove(path)
```

Try it with **print()** instead of **os.remove()** for the first run to be careful of removing inappropriate files.